# How to declare protocol constrainted generic variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, nsmutabledictionary, swift-dictionary

I need to create a dictionary variable where my value will be of `SomeOtherClass` class and conforms to `SomeProtocol`. This equals to the following declaration in Objective-C:

```
NSMutableDictionary<SomeClass *, SomeOtherClass<SomeProtocol> *> *someOtherBySome;
```

So, is it possible to do it in the same simple way using Swift?

I need it because I can create `func` with signature:

```
func someFunc<T: SomeOtherClass where T: SomeProtocol>(param: T, otherParam: String)
```

and I want to get values for `param` parameter from `Dictionary` without type casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

In Swift you cannot declare a variable of a given `class` **and** conform to a `protocol`.

### Possible solution (?)

However given the definitions you already have

```
class SomeClass: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int { return 0 } // your logic goes here
}

func ==(left:SomeClass, right:SomeClass) -> Bool {
    return true // your logic goes here
}

class SomeOtherClass {}
protocol SomeProtocol {}
```

maybe you can solve your problem simply making `SomeOtherClass` conform to `SomeProtocol`

```
extension SomeOtherClass: SomeProtocol { }
```

Now you can simply

```
var dict : [SomeClass: SomeOtherClass] = [SomeClass(): SomeOtherClass()]

let someProtocolValue: SomeProtocol = dict.values.first!
```

Does it help you?